# Multiple Alignments in Multlined Environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, multline

I'm trying to get something like the second Figure; however, the best thing I got is like Figure 1. How can I fix it?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{alignat}{2}
&\begin{multlined}[b]
\{e\}^{n+1} - \{e\}^n = \Delta t \{\dot{e}\}^{n}
+ \beta \Delta t^2 \{\ddot{e}\}^{n+1} \\
+ \Delta t^2 \left( \dfrac{1}{2}-\beta \right) \{\ddot{e}\}^{n}
\end{multlined}\\
&\dfrac{1}{\Delta t} \left( \{\dot{e}\}^{n+1}  -  \{\dot{e}\}^{n} \right)=\dfrac{1}{2} \left( \{\ddot{e}\}^{n+1}  +  \{\ddot{e}\}^{n}  \right) 
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image: Fig. 1 (Top) and Fig. 2 (Bottom)]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I can see no reason for the second type of alignment: there's no relationship between the plus and the minus.

Comment: Thanks! This is just a simple example of the problem I've faced. I didn't bring the original equation, as it is pretty long.

Answer (score 2):

Embed a `\tabbedShortstack` inside a `\Shortstack`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\stackMath
\setstackgap{S}{6pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\TABbinary
\Shortstack[l]{
\{e\}^{n+1} - \{e\}^n = \Delta t \{\dot{e}\}^{n}
+ \beta \Delta t^2 \{\ddot{e}\}^{n+1} \\
\tabbedShortstack[l]{
&+ \Delta t^2 \left( \dfrac{1}{2}-\beta \right) \{\ddot{e}\}^{n}\\
\dfrac{1}{\Delta t} \bigl( \{\dot{e}\}^{n+1}  &-  \{\dot{e}\}^{n} \bigr)=
 \dfrac{1}{2} \left( \{\ddot{e}\}^{n+1}  +  \{\ddot{e}\}^{n}  \right) }}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use an `align` environment, with a `\omit\rlap{...}` for the first line.

To have the equation number only at the end, I've used `\nonumber` for the first two rows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \omit\rlap{$\{e\}^{n+1} - \{e\}^n = \Delta t \{\dot{e}\}^{n} + \beta \Delta t^2 \{\ddot{e}\}^{n+1}$}\nonumber\\
   &{}+\Delta t^2 \left( \dfrac{1}{2}-\beta \right) \{\ddot{e}\}^{n} \nonumber\\
  \dfrac{1}{\Delta t} \left( \{\dot{e}\}^{n+1}\right. & {}-  \left.\{\dot{e}\}^{n} \right)=\dfrac{1}{2} \left( \{\ddot{e}\}^{n+1}  +  \{\ddot{e}\}^{n}  \right)
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]